# Magento 2 custom route 404 without index.php

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, routing

I have created a new module with my custom route. The frontname for my module is `vendor` and the id is `vendor`

I have created a page with route `vendor/index/index`, created a controller and block for my page. I have also created a layout file with name **frontend/layout/vendor_index_index.xml**

But when I try to access my page on frontend with url `vendor` or `vendor/index/index` it shows me 404 page. The page works if I use `index.php/vendor` or `index.php/vendor/index/index`

I am not sure about the issue as I have other modules with custom routes and they work perfectly fine without `index.php`.

I have checked and made sure that I have URL rewrite enabled in my configuration. Did anyone face any issue like this? What could be the reason and the solution for the issue?

Comment: Can you please share code, etc/module.xml, etc/frontend/routes.xml & controller code.

Comment: it's shows magento's 404 or apache/nginx 404 ?

Comment: @RakeshVarma It is showing apache/nginx 404

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Rename your `frontname` because when you access  `vendor/index/index` first it will goto the **vendor** folder not in your `controller` so in **Vendor** there is no any file for `index` that's why you are facing such issue.